# How to install updates without internet on Raspberry?

Tags: pi-2, linux, internet, dpkg

I want to calibrate my LCD screen, but i have no internet connection to my Raspberry Pi 2B.

The terminal commands I would use with internet on the Raspberry Pi is

```
cp LCD-show/xinput-calibrator_0.7.5-1_armhf.deb ~/
sudo dpkg -i -B xinput-calibrator_0.7.5-1_armhf.deb
```

How can i still calibrate  without internet?

Comment: Does that require the internet? `dpkg -i` just installs the given `.deb` - I wouldn't expect it to need the internet.  Does it fail?  What does it say?

Comment: ohhh, good point, the thins: i am a newbie. i thought that install ALWAYS requires internet

Comment: Hello. The commands you've given don't need the internet *per-se*: I'm guessing that `dpkg` is asking for support packages to be downloaded? Have you tried [apt-offline](https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT) to solve this?

Comment: You can download deb files on your laptop and move them to your Raspberry on a USB stick. Or connect your RPi to your laptop (with a cat5 cable) and use "internet connection sharing" on Windows to get the Raspberry online. Or are you located somewhere where you're off the grid?

Comment: @Dougie I suggest to make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can download deb files on your laptop and move them to your Raspberry on a USB stick.

Or connect your RPi to your laptop (with a cat5 cable) and use "internet connection sharing" on Windows to get the Raspberry online.

Unless you are located somewhere where you're off the grid.

Comment: As well as a the [apt-offline project](https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT) you can also use `apt-get --print-uris install ...` to get a list of links to DEBs to download on another PC. This will resolve any dependencies. See http://www.penguintutor.com/raspberrypi/apt-get-offline for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The above command should not require internet access.  `dpkg` simply installs `deb` files given to it.